# Bash - Removing all but a single number in output of command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, imagemagick

I'm working on a script to process all images in which the standard deviation is less than a certain threshold, e.g., if overall SD is less than 50 in x image, do y to x. The command I am using to find the SD is '*identify -verbose*', which gives an output such as:

```
 ...Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 63.7575 (0.250029)
      standard deviation: 6.45394 (0.0253096)
      kurtosis: 199663
      skewness: 5775.31...
```

Mind the output is in the ballpark of 200 lines and 8000 characters, however I need to remove all except the number after 'standard deviation: '. I managed to do it a while ago with a horribly inefficient 8+ lines of *sed* and *cut*. Any efficient methods of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: would this achieve your need? (here looking for SD > 5)

`identify -verbose | awk '/standard deviation:/ {sd=$3; if (sd > 5) print sd}'`

Comment: @tonioc The output of that command is a few lines of numbers, as there are several lines of standard deviation in the 'identify' output; I forgot to note this in my original post, however the last line of that output does give the correct number. If I were to remove the first 4 lines of that, it would give exactly what I am looking for. I'll post a one-line solution to this if I can find one.

Comment: So still using awk to catch the last SD value, my answer would look like: `identify -verbose | awk 'BEGIN {sd=0} /standard deviation:/ {sd=$3;} END {print sd}'` . Note: the END clause can also include an 'if' statement.

Comment: @tonioc You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)